# Duplicate h1 on single post page, blog page and category pages in WordPress

Tags: seo, wordpress, blog, h1

I am working on SEO for a website - the site is built with Divi which uses h2 for the post titles on the single post page; I have changed the h2 to h1 by creating a child theme and editing the index.php template page, to help with the site's SEO. However, I am faced with an issue now: I ran a crawl for the site on ahrefs.com and the report shows duplicate h1's across the single post page, the blog page and category pages (which is to be expected). My question is, will this affect the SEO of the website in a negative way? If yes, how could I get around this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Wasi

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't. Google knows that this kind of issue happens and they can read the content of the page visually too, so you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Hi Andre,                                                                                                                Thanks for the answer, can you you please explain what you mean when you say "they can read the content of the page visually too"? Thanks

Comment: To add to Andre's information. Great post here by Google's John Mueller on this topic from early Jan this year
https://www.searchenginejournal.com/heading-tags-for-seo/341817/

Comment: @WasiUllah what I meant was that they use the actual rendered text for this too, which means they know the top text at the top is the most important one, regardless if you mark that as an H1 or H2, or if there's more than one.

Yes, ideally you should make it easier for them by implementing these best-practices but I doubt what you described will generate anybig issues for you.